# Changing the order of PlatformViews (iFrame) in a Stack causes the render to fail

Tags: html, flutter, web, iframe, flutter-web

A possible fix would be to avoid using Keys in the Positioned widget (L: 42) but this would cause the internal state of the HtmlElementView (or other displayed items such as videos) to reset their state as they are actually disposed.

In the example below, maybe the usage of the platform factory is wrongly implemented or Keys aren't supposed to be used like this. However, I suspect this to be related to DOM & Flutter's SDK.

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<int> order = [
    1,
    2,
  ];

  void _reverseOrder() {
    setState(() {
      order = order.reversed.toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
          children: order
              .map<Widget>((o) => Positioned(
                    key: Key(o.toString() + o.toString()),
                    /*
                    key is used
                    */
                    left: o * 100,
                    top: o * 100,
                    width: o * 250,
                    height: o * 250,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        child(o),
                        Center(child: Text(o.toString())),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ))
              .toList()),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _reverseOrder,
        tooltip: 'Reverse order of widgets',
        child: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

Widget child(int id) {
  return createIFrame(
    'sample.pdf',
    id.toString(),
  );

  // // Works without issues with non platform widgets
  // return Container(
  //   color: Color.fromARGB(255, 100 * id, 100 * id, 100 * id),
  // );
}

Widget createIFrame(
  String url,
  String id,
) {
  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
    id,
    (int viewId) => html.IFrameElement()..src = url,
  );
  return HtmlElementView(viewType: id);
}
```

Useful links:

[HtmlElementView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/HtmlElementView-class.html)

[platform-views-using-html-slots-web](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/platform-views-using-html-slots-web)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually an issue in the SDK.
It got fixed by the flutter team after it was raised to their attention.

[flutter/issues/101580](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/101580#issuecomment-1094658845).